# how to add registration form in drupal block in a popup box in home page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to add a registration form in a popup on home page in drupal, with fade in fade out functionality. Is there any module available to do so? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try https://drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal

and use hook_form_alter() to edit registration form
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

I used it for making popup contact form, worked like a charm
Maybe you will need some jQuery customisation for fadeout or other jQuery effects

Answer (score 1):

Add this module & Configure it...

https://drupal.org/project/ajax_register

OR

https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms